# Datatables Filtering - an exact match in smart seach

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, datatables

I want to persist with the smart search ( search as i type ) that datatables has. The problem is, one of my columns shows values like: person and personnel. So with million records, it is hard for me to dig down to "person" with the column just showing "personnel" when i type "person".

I do not want only exact match. That would make me type the whole name as in : "person-xyz-123" in some cases.

Is there a way for me to specify say "person" in quotes and tell datatables that i just want to do exact search when i type in quotes and still persist with my normal search ?

Coffeescript file:

```
$(xyz).ready ->
    $('#xyz').dataTable
      bProcessing: true
      bServerSide: true
      sDom: "<\"top\"T>rt<\"bottom\"lip><\"clear\">"
      oTableTools:
        sSwfPath: "../TableTools-2.1.5/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
      sAjaxSource: $('#xyz').data('source')
    .columnFilter aoColumns: [
      { type: "text" },
      { type: "text" },
      { type: "text" },
      { type: "text" },
      { type: "text" },
      { type: "text" },
      { type: "text" },
      { type: "text" },
      {
      type: "select"
      values: [
        {"value": 0, "label": "Failed"},
        {"value": 1, "label": "Completed"},
        {"value": 2, "label": "Processing"}
      ]
      }
    ]
    return
```

Comment: Are you doing this using server-side processing?

Comment: Yes. I have copied the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm assuming a 1.9 API since this is what you seem to be using in the question.)

It is possible to do what you want but this means modifying the server-side code that answers to requests made to the URL you give as the `sAjaxSource` option. It must perform these checks:

1. If the `sSearch` parameter (which is added to the `sAjaxSource` URL) contains a term in double quotes like `"person"` then remove the double quotes and perform the match exactly.
2. Otherwise perform a partial match.

The full documentation of what DataTables sends to the server and what it expects is [here](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side).

Comment: Can you give an example for your suggestion ?Thanks

Comment: I'd know how to do it with Django but I don't do Ruby-on-Rails.

Comment: I think i figured it out. I will post when i have clean code. Thanks

Comment: Glad to read it! Sorry I did not respond earlier. Busy... and I get quite a bit of responses to my comments here.

Comment: Not a problem. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I created this helper function to solve my problem:

```
  def filter_helper(data)
    return "#{data[:name]} = :search", search: "#{params[data[:dt_name]].gsub!(/^\"|\"?$/, '') }" if "#{params[data[:dt_name]]}".chars.first == "\""
    return "#{data[:name]} like :search", search: "%#{params[data[:dt_name]]}%" if "#{params[data[:dt_name]]}".chars.first != "\""
  end
```